# Finding String in Text file printing line to a new file Python 2.7

Tags: python, text-parsing

```
 x = "mama"
 with open("testing.txt") as search:
     for line in search:
         line = line.rstrip()
         if x == line:
             print line
```

testing.txt is a file containing the lyrics from Bohemian Rhapsody. Above all I am trying to get it to do is just print a line. I have attempted several different types of set ups which can be seen below. They are shown as commented out because I've been just commenting out everything that I can't get to work. There was probably other code that went along with each of them at some point but the --- lines separate everything I've tried.

```
#searchquery = 'mama\n'

#with open('testing.txt', 'r') as f1:
#   with open('616.txt', 'w') as f2:
#      for line in f1:
#         if line == searchquery:
#            print line
#            f2.write(line)
#            f2.write(f1.next())
#            f2.write(f2.next())
#f1.close()
#f2.close()

#        -----------------------------------------------

#searchquery = 'mama\n'
#x=57
#to open the files for below I did something like:
#with open("testing.txt", r) as f1:
#    with open("614.txt", w) as f2:
#while i <=x:
#    if lines[i] == searchquery:
#            f2.write(Lines[i])
#            f2.write(Lines[i+1])
#            f2.write(Lines[i+2])             
#    else:
#        i = i+1
#    

#----------------------
```

I'm just trying to learn some basics. And I'm certain I'm looking something over. If it's in # I was not concerned with proper indention when I was coping it in here. Think of that as more of notes that I've been keeping while attempting this small code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your problem is that nothing is being printed out.

The first code on your question is almost there, the issue is that by checking for equality (`==`) the print would only be executed if the line is exactly the value of `x`. You could use the `in` operator instead of equality

```
x = "mama"
with open("testing.txt") as search:
     for line in search:
         line = line.rstrip()
         if x in line:
             print line
```

Comment: It still doesn't print anything. I honestly think it is just searching the first line.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `if` and just always print `line`?

Comment: ()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
() and it continues... Just to be completely clear there are some lines that have () in the txt file but not that many.

Comment: So, I decided to write up an if else statement and have it print "not here" if it can't find the word I'm looking for. It printed "not here" 57 times. So the issue is that it isn't finding the key word I'm looking for. (Just going to keep looking if you respond awesome but if I find my solution I'll let you know! Thanks!)

Comment: with open("testing.txt", "r") as f:
    with open("624.txt", "w") as f1:
        for line in f:
            if "mama" in line.lower():
                f1.write(line)

Ended up being my solution. My problem was that my flag was capitalized in the file I was searching. silly.